# Checking the number of machines

Tags: security, cryptography, license-key, product-key

I wish to seek suggestions on th following:

While creating a product key if one wish to use the no. of machines the key is made for , just like in the case of Microsoft Volume Licensing , how can one do that so that easily verfiable inside the dll which is made to verfiy the key entered in the installer and say if a key is made for say 100 machines how does one validate it offline that the product key does not work on 101th computer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called 'floating licenses'. You can have a 'license server' that reserves N seats for specific local area network. When an instance of application is launched it connects to the 'license server' and queries a permission to run. If there are already N connections, N+1 instance start up will be denied.

Check the http://activation-cloud.com it might be useful for you.

Comment: Just a note: rules require that you disclose affiliation with the link and despite the fact that the names are the same, I'd suggest writing that this is your service or that you are affiliated (otherwise some people who don't read well can flag your message as spam or downvote it).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without a central server which validates installations and (more importantly) activations and uses.

Comment: :Even if i need to have a centralized server and there is a single key for say 100 machines how would i check on the server that the current m/c is not 101 may bethrough key no.

Comment: @LindaHarrison the question is quite broad to be answered in this format. Your best bet would be to use some activation service similar to the one mentioned in another answer. At least read how activations work in real world, then you'll know what to implement and will know particular questions to ask.

Answer (score 0):

one way is central server and floating license (as ActivationCloud said). other way is to have serial numbers of physical devices. e.g. some companies sell soft that is intended to run only on pendrive and you have to provide the serial number before downloading the program. the number is automatically inserted into the program and this prepared program is downloaded by the client. this particular program will not run (without hacking it) on any other device